# Deploying ASP.NET MVC projects into test server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment

This is a general question regarding deploying an MVC asp.net app into a test server.

How do you do it?

I tried to publish and deploy an mvc app into test server (under tight control), and the VS.NET complained that it was not able to update the remote IIS server for creating the virtual directory etc there, although the remote machine is accessible via its IP address.

Comment: Can you try deploying a Normal ASP.NET app and see if you can do it?
If you can't deploy normal ASP.NET app then there is nothing to do with MVC app!

Answer (score 2):

Check this MSDN Help Page and make sure you meet all the requirments to manage/setup/configure remote IIS sites.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h17hytcs.aspx

fyi: there should not be any difference between regular asp.net and mvc sites.

Comment: So effectively, i guess i will need an admin rights account to the test server (atleast to be able to run the task of creting virtual directoris, setting up app pool, etc)
and a Shared folder in test server visible to me so that i can XCOPY the app files into there (which will be mapped as to the Virtual directory for the app in IIS as in earlier poiunt above).

Correct?